# hex encode in sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

http://www.pwntester.com/blog/2014/01/15/hackyou2014-web100-write-up/
At this link, They have injected by hex code like

```
0x39393939393939393939393920756e696f6e20616c6c202873656c656374202748656c6c6f21212729
```

meaning:

```
999999999999 union all (select 'Hello!!')
```

In mysql,we cannot type a query like 
Mysql> 0x0abcd... (assume that 0x0abc.. mean select * from...). 
So, Can you explain for me why can they inject as in my link?
p/s: Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: Please include an explanation of the hack in that blog post so that this question can stand on its own. That link will inevitably rot.

Comment: People who are voting to close this question because it is not clear are being way too picky. This question is perfectly clear and appropriate.

Comment: As for being too picky, the edit makes a huge difference, having to read a remote link is not reasonable (the relevant detail should be copied in to the question), and this is a problem with PHP, not mysql/sql. Combined, those still make it unclear.

Comment: @rolfl, then suggesting an edit to improve the question is appropriate. Doing a drive-by close vote is not helpful, and is like a door slammed in the face to someone who is asking for help.

Answer (score 4):

The SQL injection does not happen in the `INSERT` statement but in the second `SELECT` statement:

```
"SELECT title FROM picture WHERE id = ".$r['id']
```

Here `$r['id']` is the recently inserted ID, i. e., the user supplied `$_POST['id']` value.

Now the reason for why this SQL injection works is MySQL’s support for [hexadecimal literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) and the fact that the *id* column of the *vote* table is of a [string type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-types.html) as in that case the following applies:

> In string contexts, they act like binary strings, where each pair of hex digits is converted to a character:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT X'4D7953514C';
>         -> 'MySQL'
> mysql> SELECT 0x0a+0;
>         -> 10
> mysql> SELECT 0x5061756c;
>         -> 'Paul'
> ```

For PHP `0x…` is numeric (i. e., `is_numeric`) and for MySQL `0x…` is interpreted and stored as string, which later gets inserted into the above mentioned `SELECT` statement.

This wouldn’t be possible if either

- *id* would have been a numeric data type, or
- the `SELECT` would have been a prepared statement.

Comment: in that link, they use hex code not only as d column,but also as a query(0x39... as 99999 UNION...), and I cannot do something like that in mysql commandline.

Comment: @theasker228 That only works because the string value given in hex is stored in the database and later retrieved and inserted into another query.

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in the comments on that blog post. The hex string must be run through PHP, or some other system which *incorrectly* passes the value to MySQL as a string (instead of a number), in order for this "hack" to work.

Comment: i am sure that the hex string just go through PHP. Can you point out which component in PHP code has converted the hex string into string?